# Applications of Topological Complexity of configuration space

Tags: algebraic-topology, applications, robotics

I'm starting to work on Topological Complexity of configuration spaces .
Articles say that it has applications in robotic and control theory .
One important article belongs to [Michael Farber](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh5qbh4Y3OAhXI8RQKHZ0_D7cQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.uchicago.edu%2F~shmuel%2FAAT-readings%2FRobotics%2FFarber%2520robotics%2520survey.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGCsplS180LCvDm90UIZlYsIKpfKg&sig2=BsPFjsgZgIlMGiQlnOGQ8w)

My questions are :
1) How can Topological complexity be applied in Robotic and control theory ?
2) Does there exist any Applied problems in Robotic and Control or other subjects that can be solved using notions of Topological complexity ?

Thanks

Comment: If someone went out of their way to define something concretely, it almost certainly clarifies something else or helps to solve a problem.

Comment: There are some references for this kind of thing in Robert Ghrist's book available here https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/notes.html